# Deploy a web project in a web tomcat using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, eclipse-plugin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remote deploy Tomcat webapp from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760297/remote-deploy-tomcat-webapp-from-eclipse)

I would like to know if is possible to deploy a web service from eclipse directly to a tomcat server that it is host is in a different computer ? and if it is possible how to do it ?

best regards