# Sharing Tomcat Configuration With Team Members

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, svn, tomcat7, collaboration

I'm setting up a tomcat 7 configuration (jdbc, app deployment, classpath, etc.) from Eclipse on a local tomcat installation that I want to share with some team members. My first attempt is to commit the Servers folder (a folder that Eclipse creates when you create a local server configuration in your workspace) and tell my team mates to check it out but I'm not sure if this approach can work.

Is this the correct approach of sharing a local tomcat configuration?

If not, can you give me some suggestions?

P.S. I'm not setting up a centralized/networked tomcat server yet, since we are at a phase when we deploy and test our code locally, even though we integrate our code on SVN.

Comment: Indeed, in my group we are facing a similar problem, and there's no other way than backing up parts of the workspace in svn. However, depending on the configuration you want to backup, it gets tricky. In you case, in the Servers folder of the workspace you get to backup only generic configuration of tomcat. If you want to backup the debugging config, e.g. because you are adding jars manually to the servers (classpath tab), you need to backup the dir .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches/Tomcat7... which is platform dependent and installation-dependent -there's absolute paths.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remote deploy Tomcat webapp from Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760297/remote-deploy-tomcat-webapp-from-eclipse)